# Passing props / arguments to HOCs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, apollo-client

I am trying to pass props (or an argument) to this HOC. I would like to be able to set the uri here dynamically:

```
import withApollo from 'next-with-apollo';
import ApolloClient, { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-boost';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

export default withApollo(
  ({ initialState }) => {
    return new ApolloClient({
      uri: 'https://example.com/graphql',
      cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || {})
    });
  },
  {
    render: ({ Page, props }) => {
      return (
        <ApolloProvider client={props.apollo}>
          <Page {...props} />
        </ApolloProvider>
      );
    }
  }
);
```

I don't really use HOCs normally, so not sure the best way to go about this. If I pass the variable to as a Page prop. How can I access it in the ApolloClient object? Or if that's not possible how would I set an argument here and then access it in the HOC?

```
export default withApollo(HomePage);
```

Thanks for any help offered!

Comment: Why not pass the variable directly in the `uri` field? How were you planning on using the HOC if you could pass a dynamic `uri` to it?

Comment: You probably don't want an HOC there. The HOC is a convenience to easily add the shared Apollo client to a page, but is not meant at creating a new client dynamically (since  you need one client per URI).  Use it only if you know the URI in advance.